# Filter Podio Items by Item ID

Tags: podio

I'm having a bit of an issue getting a collection of Podio items from an app by item ids.

According to [this post](https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201809028-How-to-get-a-list-of-items-by-item-ids), Andreas said that "... you can now filter by item_id (and app_item_id). Just use item_id or app_item_id as the filter key and give it an array of item ids ...".

So I'm trying to get a bunch of items in one shot to reduce API calls with:

```
$attributes = ["filter" => [
    "item_id" => [12345,23456]
]];
$items = PodioItem::filter( $app_id, $attributes );
```

But I'm always getting all items back from the app, not just the 2 items listed in the filter.

Anyone come across this anomaly before? Workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `$attributes` array in the wrong format.
You have to pass it in `filters` array like,

```
$attributes = ["filters" => [
    "item_id" => [12345,23456]
]];
$items = PodioItem::filter( $app_id, $attributes );
```

You will get back only the mentioned items [12345,23456].

Comment: OMG! Such a rookie mistake. Thanks!